# Moved wordpress site links still pointing old server

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting, database-migration

i've moved a wordpress site from one server to another , its a big project and  i did everything   correctly but there seems to be bit of  issue with some of the links  when i click them they are still pointing to old   server instead of new one , whats wrong with this can some one help me with this ,

for installation i downloaded everything from public_html and uploaded to new server ,  created  databases  and linked it in  wp-config files , All these link  are  being  generated dynamically in front-page template  but still  going to old server

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the value of "siteurl" and "home" in wp_options table?

Check if the old URL exists in that table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_options` 
WHERE  `option_value` LIKE  '%old_url_here%'
```

Comment: can i do it using code  instead of going to db  table ?

Comment: Yes: `<?php echo get_option( 'siteurl' ); ?>` and `<?php echo get_option( 'home' ); ?>`